# Powershell, compare 2 txt files and output the difference side by side in a txt file

Tags: powershell

compare 2 txt files and output the difference side by side in a txt file.

```
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $(Get-Content c:\user.txt) -DifferenceObject 
$(Get-Content c:\user_old.txt) | format-table -auto -hidetableheaders  
>C:\user_check.txt
```

**user.txt**

```
 new_id   new_lname   new_fname
   1        Jones       Mike
   2        Lewis       Don
   3        Smith       Melissa
   4        Grady       Sue
```

**user_old.txt**

```
 old_id   old_lname   old_fname
   1        Jones       Mikey
   2        Lewis       Don
   3        Williams    Melissa
   4        Grady       Susan
```

**Results**

```
  old_id   old_lname   old_fname  =>
  1        Jones       Mikey      =>
  3        Williams    Melissa    =>
  4        Grady       Susan      =>
  new_id   new_lname   new_fname  <=
  1        Jones       Mike       <=
  3        Smith       Melissa    <=
  4        Grady       Sue        <=
```

**This is what I want**

```
old_id   old_lname   old_fname  =>      new_id   new_lname   new_fname  <=
1        Jones       Mikey      =>      1        Jones       Mike       <=
3        Williams    Melissa    =>      3        Smith       Melissa    <=
4        Grady       Susan      =>      4        Grady       Sue        <=
```

Comment: How do you decide how each of the rows would line up? Or are you just wanting the columns to show regardless of line difference? Would you like CSV Ouput? That would make this easier the rolling a line building logic process

Comment: The old_id and new_id are the same, user can not edit, they can only edit the first name and last name.  CSV Output may work.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the cleanest approach to this. But since you know when you compare there will two output objects one with `<=` as a `SideIndicator` and one with the `=>`. And they should be in the same order. So if you split them into two arrays and then output the a string from both arrays using the same index, you'll get your output string.

```
$compare = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $(Get-Content c:\temp\user.txt) -DifferenceObject $(Get-Content c:\temp\user_old.txt)
$rights = $compare | ? {$_.sideindicator -eq "=>"}
$lefts = $compare | ? {$_.sideindicator -eq "<="}
foreach ($right in $rights) {
    "$($right.InputObject) `t $($right.SideIndicator)  $($lefts[([array]::indexof($Rights,$right))].InputObject) `t $($lefts[([array]::indexof($Rights,$right))].SideIndicator)"
}
```

Comment: Since you are assuming the order and number of lines are guaranteed would it not have been easier to just step through the lines and pull each one out? ``0..($rights.count -1) | Foreach {"$($lefts[$_])`t$($rights[$_])"}``.. simplified for comments of course.